# How to fix angular z-Index is not a known CSS property

Tags: css, angular

I get the following

```
[webpack-dev-server] WARNING
▲ [WARNING] "z-Index" is not a known CSS property

    styles.css:119530:2:
      119530 │   z-Index: 10;
             │   ~~~~~~~
             ╵   z-index

  Did you mean "z-index" instead?
```

I do understand somewhere a css `z-index` is wrongly declared, but I don't find it anywhere in my code & I do not have any `styles.css` file.

Does somebody have an Idea on the reason behind it, or how I can find it ?

*I'm pretty sur it is coming from a library I've imported, but do not know how to find which*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered this problem when building an app using [openlayers](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers) library. It has been fixed in version 6.13.0.

Comment: I confirm this did fix the problem. I had to migrate to the v`6.14.2-dev.1651201371595`  because the version 6.13.0 had some typing errors

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to worry about, it's a build time warning only, it comes from `@coreui/coreui@2.1.x` CSS styles library (kind of workaround for lack of support for CSS custom properties in internet explorer).

Answer (score 0):

So, to be more precise.

### Reason

This is happening if `z-Index` is written in a css file

### Fix: local

Search for this text an replace it.

### Fix: dependency

If you didn't find anything, it mean that this error happen in **one of the library you have imported**.

You cannot do nothing to fix it *appart creating an issue or a pull request in the library that contains the error*

For what I know, it doesn't exists any easy way to find from which library this warning come from.

### Important ?

No, this isn't and you shall safely ignore this, if the `Fox: local` didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

config like this ：

`{
"$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
.
.
.
"projects": {
"my-project": {
.
.
.
"architect": {
"build": {
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
"options": {
.
.
.
},
"configurations": {
"production": {
.
.
.
},
"development": { // add this block
"buildOptimizer": false,
"optimization": false,
"vendorChunk": true,
"extractLicenses": false,
"sourceMap": true,
"namedChunks": true
}
},
}`

Tested on angular 13.*

Comment: I would rater not implement that since this is only a warning and here you're removing some security check.